# Audio Player button

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I'd like to create a simple app with two buttons and when you press on the button, there is a sound . But when I try with this code, nothing append when I press the button...

What's wrong?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func button1(sender: AnyObject) {

        var player1: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


        let audioPath1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("song1", ofType: "mp3")!

        do {

            try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath1))


        } catch {

            // Process error here

        }


        player1.play()


    }

    @IBAction func button2(sender: AnyObject) {

        var player2: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

        let audioPath2 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("song2", ofType: "mp3")!

        do {

            try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath2))


        } catch {

            // Process error here

        }

        player2.play()

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Ensure the function is connected to to correct action of UIButton in your storyboard/nib.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
  import UIKit
  import AVFoundation

 class TestAudio: UIViewController {


    var ButtonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FileName", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var ButtonAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       do {
           try ButtonAudioPlayer  = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonAudioURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
       } catch {
           print("errorin do-try-catch")
       }
   }  


   @IBAction func PlayFirstAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
       if ButtonAudioPlayer.playing == true {
           ButtonAudioPlayer.stop()
       } else {
           ButtonAudioPlayer.play()
       }
   }
}
```